# random white-space being added to subnav li's

Tags: css, navigation

http://www.occmedjackson.com/services/

See the left sidebar nav.  The last LI should not drop down.  Viewing the source, there's no reason it should be doing this.  When i inspect it in chrome though, i see a random double quote (which does not display) showing up in the generated code.  That seems to be what's pushing this down.  This only happens when our clients adds to the menu using Dreamweaver, though when I use dreamweaver it does not happen.

Any ideas what this is, what's causing it, or a solution to keep it from happening (or to add some js or css to fix it if it does)?  As it is, i need to recreate the menu each time to fix.

Thanks!  Rich!

Comment: The extra quote is causing this problem. I suggest you give your client Notepad++ or some other NON-WYSIWYG editor, or move to a CMS where the user can edit the menus but does not have direct access to the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problematic character is the closing bracket of the `<li> <--`
If you delete that > and the open bracket of the `<a` tag and type in your own the whitespace disappears. 
Your users could possibly be typing out their code in MS Word (or some other editing software) and pasting it into Dreamweaver.

replace `><`